# Delete Child record with Parent Foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a one-to-many relationship with child-parent with a list of the children in the parent, I deleted the list but in the database it only deletes the parents Id,

[image]

> Parent:

```
  public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<VehicleCategory> builder)
    {

        builder.OwnsOne(o => o.Name,
            sa =>
            {
                sa.Property("StringValue").HasColumnName("Name").IsUnicode(true).IsRequired();
                sa.Ignore("CurrentCultureText");
            });

        var navigation = builder.Metadata.FindNavigation(nameof(VehicleCategory.Successors));
        navigation.SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
        builder.Property(c => c.IsActive);
        builder.Property(c => c.Sequence);
    }
```

> Child

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<VehicleSuccessorCategory> builder)
    {
        builder.HasOne<VehicleCategory>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(p => p.SuccessorId).IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        builder.Property(e => e.Order).IsRequired();
    }
```

> Clearing the list

```
 public virtual void DeleteAll()
    {
        _successors.Clear();
    }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete You have set your deletebehavior property to "restrict" and you are looking for "cascade".

Comment: I did set it to cascade and is not working either

Comment: could you paste your delete code?

Comment: I updated the code

Comment: @sam please have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
builder.HasOne<VehicleCategory>().WithMany(e => e.Successors).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade).IsRequired();
```

Comment: Please add an explanation.

Comment: it was because of the relationship I had between the parent and child.
it was one-many from both side. 
`.HasForeignKey(p => p.SuccessorId)`